# Вызов ArrayList из другого метода

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обратиться из метода `Onclick(...)` к `ArrayList`, который был создан в методе `OnCreate(...)`?

Пока сделал так:

**OnCreate(...)**:

```
ArrayList<Integer> Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();
for (int a = 1; a < 8; a++) {
    Arrayl.add(a);
}
Collections.shuffle(Arrayl);// перемешиваем
```

в **Onclick(...)**:

```
int actvopros= Arrayl.get(0); //и такое обращение не работает
```

Answer (score 5):

*Скорее всего* Ваша проблема заключается в том, что коллекцию `Arrayl` Вы объявляете как **локальную переменную** метода `OnCreate(...)`, которая вне этого метода видна не будет.

Для того, чтобы получить доступ к этой переменной из других методов (этого же класса), коллекцию `Arrayl` нужно объявить как поле класса:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Integer> Arrayl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int a = 1; a < 8; a++) {
            Arrayl.add(a);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrayl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявляй вне методов, инициализируй в OnCreate и используй где хочешь.

```
class A {    
    private ArrayList Arrayl;
    ...
    OnCreate {
    ...
    Array1 = new ArrayList<>() 
    ....
    }
    void B { Array1 будет видно. }
}
```

Вот так.